# Backbone updating Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, model-view-controller, view, frontend

I am making a Rails app using Backbone on the frontend. I have two views, one for a Publication model and one for an Article model. In the Publication view there is a 'createFeed' function that gets executed when the user fills out a form and clicks the button. When that happens I would like the database to get updated then for the two views to get re-rendered. So far with no luck.

Here is the Backbone Router function that initially renders both views:

```
home: function(){
    var publications = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Publications();
    publications.fetch({
      success: function(publications){
        var view = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.PublicationsIndex({model: publications});
        view.render();
      }

    });

    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    articles.fetch({
      success: function(articles){
        var view = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.ArticlesIndex({model: articles});
        view.render();
      }
    });
  },
```

This is the createFeed function in my Publication View in Backbone. The post requests work fine, now just trying to figure out how to update the views.

```
  createFeed: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var feed_url = $('#new_feed_name').val();

    $.post('/publications', {url: feed_url}, function(){
      $.post('/articles/force_update', {feed_url: feed_url}, function(){
          // should I put something here?
      });
    });

  }
```

I have tried copying the code I have in my Router's home function into the callback for createFeed which updated the articles just fine but caused problems when updating the publication view, I guess because that is having the view render itself from within one of its functions. I have also tried including this in the view as well but not working.

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
},
```

How to get createFeed to update both views after it sends the proper data to the database?

Any input is appreciated!

*** UPDATE ***

Rida BENHAMMANE and Jon McMillan thanks for the input.

I now have update the router's 'home' function as such:

```
 home: function(){
    var publications = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Publications();
    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    var pubIndex = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.PublicationsIndex({model: publications});
    var artIndex = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.ArticlesIndex({model: articles});

    // create a method to replace the force_update post in your publications view
    articles.listenTo(publications, "add", articles.force_update);
    publications.fetch();
    articles.fetch();
  },
```

and the createFeed function with my Publication view like this:

```
  createFeed: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var feed_url = $('#new_feed_name').val();

    this.model.create({
        url: feed_url
    });
  }
```

This is per Jon's suggestion. It works great in terms of making the post and rendering the Publication view. Of course now I have to write the code to post to articles and update it's view accordingly per Jon's comment.

Is this something I should do separately in the Articles view? Or can I do it here in my createFeed function in the Publication view? If I do it separately then would I now have two views both having functions for the same event?

**SOLUTION! ***

publication index view

```
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "sync", this.render);
  },

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template({publications: this.model.toJSON()}) );
    return this;
  },

  createFeed: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var feed_url = $('#new_feed_name').val();
    var that = this;

    this.model.create(
      {url: feed_url},
      { success: function(data){
          $.post('/articles/force_update', {url: feed_url, publication_id: data.id}, function(data){});
        }
      }
    );

  }
```

Publication Router

```
  home: function(){

    var publications = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Publications();
    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    var pubIndex = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.PublicationsIndex({model: publications});
    var artIndex = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.ArticlesIndex({model: articles});

    //method to replace the force_update post in your publications view
    articles.listenTo(publications, "sync", function(){
      // var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
      articles.fetch( {success: function(){}} );
    });

    publications.fetch();

  },
```

I can move on with my life after two days. Lol. Thanks for the input guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sync` like described in another post already made or a number of other events.

Refer to [Collection.create()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) and [Collection.fetch()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) for which events you can `listenTo`.

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "sync", this.render);
},
createFeed: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var feed_url = $('#new_feed_name').val();

    this.model.create({
        url: feed_url
    });
}
```

You can listen for the `add` event in the Router to trigger the second post.  The view for the articles can listen for some event triggered by the `force_update` post to render, much like the initialize function above.

```
home: function() {
    var publications = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Publications();
    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    var pubIndex = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.PublicationsIndex({model: publications});
    var artIndex = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.ArticlesIndex({model: articles});

    // create a method to replace the force_update post in your publications view
    articles.listenTo(publications, "add", articles.force_update);
    publications.fetch();
    articles.fetch();
}
```

By listening to `sync`, you can remove the `fetch({success:fn})` callback.

**Update**

The main idea is to leverage Backbone's event system to talk between the collections and the views.  If the standard use cases apply to you, use Backbone's defaults otherwise make use of `trigger("custom-event")`.

Inside the declaration of `SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles`

```
        // collection "add" event callbacks pass the model as the first n
        // param to the callback
        force_update: function(publication) {
            var data = {
                feed_url: publication.get("url")
            };

            var callback = _.bind(function() {
                this.trigger('force-update');
            }, this);

            $.post('/articles/force_update', data).done(callback);
        }
    });
```

Inside the `SimpleGoogleReader.Views.ArticlesIndex`

```
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.model, "force-update", this.render);
        }
```

Comment: This worked! I need to take the time to familiarize myself with the render method.

Comment: Do you require the new publication to finish being created (response from server) before posting to articles?

Comment: Yes I do. I started a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821134/backbone-shall-i-use-sync-or-jquery-can-i-listen-for-either/21824742?noredirect=1#21824742

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is :

1- Use the `sync` function of the backbone collection to persist its state to the server instead of using `$.post()`

2- Bind the `sync` event to the views rendering :

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this.model, "sync", this.render);
}
```

3- Keep a reference to your collections somewhere, so whenever you want to update your server with the client state, call the collections `sync` method and if it completes successfully yours views will be rerendered.

Comment: Sorry this is a little confusing, how do I use sync? New to Backbone.

Comment: You can use it like this `publications.sync('update');` http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sync